# Make Sprites Responsive Using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I tried to make responsive sprites (backgroud Image) using CSS3. Like I have done this but nothing is shown in the div, I think there should be some contents (but I don't want to put any content) so that div get some height, then the background image will be shown.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cbs-news-logo"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cbs-news-logo { 
    background-position: 0 27.272727%; 
    background-size: 122.439024%; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    background-image: url('logos.png'); 
}
```

I tried many links, but cannot find a good one.

Comment: You probably need to set an `min-width`/`min-height` attribute to the `div` CSS.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too ... but like if I do `min-height: 20px` of `div` then still it is not responsive. Can you please come-up with a responsive sprite example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **simplest** solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cbs-news-logo"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cbs-news-logo { 
    background-position: 0 27.272727%; 
    background-size: 122.439024%; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    background-image: url('logos.png'); 
    padding-bottom: 16%;  // This will give height to the div and make the div responsive so the (background) image behaves as responsive image.
}
```

If you want to see the [demo](http://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/ekuxb).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cbs-news-logo { 
  
    background-image:url('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    min-height:125px; // if u want change hear 
    max-width:800px;  // if u want change hear
}
```

```html
<div class="cbs-news-logo"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Well its not the case ... It will not make the sprites responsive because what if I have multiple images in one sprite ... I your case it has fix `height`. In simple words `px` does not make anything responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you..

```
.cbs-news-logo{ // Responsive background
  background: url('logos.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: NNN px) { // if you do not want to show any content until some properties ( note that now is max-with, but it can be other )
  .cbs-news-logo{ (...)
}
```